# Prove that if $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 5|x-y|^{1.2}$ than $f$ is a constant function ($f(x) = c$)

Tags: calculus

I tried rephrasing $f(y)$ as $f(x+a)$ and prove this statement for any a, but I eventually get to:
$$|f(x+a)-f(x)|\leq 5|a|^{1.2}$$

Comment: It is better to write $f(x+a)=f(a)+o(x)$ in other words $f$ admits a derivative in $a$ and $f'(a)=0$.

Comment: I haven't read the answers yet, And I always up-vote and click V when I accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: calculate the derivative:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \cdots$$

Comment: I didn't do that, but I did the following:
$|{f(x)-f(x_0)}|\leq 5|{x-x_0}|^1.2 \leq |{x-x_0}|$
I know that $|x-x_0|$ is always positive therefore it is smaller than the last expression.
Than I get:
$\frac{|{f(x)-f(x_0)}|}{|x-x_0|}\leq 0 $
I think this completes the proof right? the derivative is always zero.

Comment: And even without getting into the derivative, can I say that because $f(x)-f(x_0) = 0$ than $f(x_0)=f(x)$ for any $x$?

Comment: @Agami, $|(f(x)-f(x_0))/(x-x_0)|\le 5|x-x_0|^{0.2}$. This implies $f'(x_0) = 0$. But taking the limit is required.

Comment: Yeah I messed up.
So i'm just stuck:
$\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|} \leq 5|x-x_0|^{0.2}$
I have no idea how to continue from here. I want to get rid of the expression on the right side and just stay with $0$ but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 2):

You have: $0 \leq \left|\dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}\right|\leq 5|a|^{0.2}$. Thus using squeeze theorem, you obtain $\displaystyle \lim_{a\to 0} \left|\dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}\right|=0$,and since $-\left|\dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}\right| \leq \dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a} \leq \left|\dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}\right|$, using squeeze theorem once more you have: $\displaystyle \lim_{a\to 0} \dfrac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a} = 0\Rightarrow f'(x) = 0\Rightarrow f(x) = C$

Comment: How did you obtain that $\lim_{a\to0}|{\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}}|=0$? I only know that it is $\leq 5|a|^{1.2}$